# Display datastore entity by ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

i am really new with Google App Engine

I am trying to make a simple blog where the blog visitors can comment.

The entity properties are 'Title' and 'Content'

I managed to grab hold of the datastore ID by using {{post.key.id()}} and past it to another HTML page. The problem is, i am unable to display the content by the ID

For example, i want to display the BlogPost Title:-
I tried  - 
The title of the post is {{title.ID()}}
The content is {{content.ID()}}

I don't know the actual Syntax for it. May i know the right syntax?

Appreciate your kind help

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the entity Key, you just need to use `get()` method to retrieve the entity content from Datastore. In Python, you would do this:

```
post = post.key.get()
```

Then you can access the post content as properties of the post object:

```
post_title = post.title
post_content = post.content
```

For more info, see the [Gogle Datastore CRUD documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities#Python_retrieving_entities) (using Python NDB library). You'll find similar docs there for other languages.